# Formsubmit doesn't show me the information of the person who submits the form

Tags: html, css, github, frontend, bootstrap-5

I am creating a website using Bootstrap 5 and I am hosting the website using GitHub pages. I also used Bootstrap 5 to create a contact form on the website. I am using [Formsubmit](https://formsubmit.co/) to send the info submitted to the form to my email. When  I submit the form I get an email but the email doesn't show me anything that is submitted in the form. This is what the email I get looks like [image]

### Test.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Home | </title>

<meta name="description" content="Write an awesome description for your new site here. It will appear in your document head meta (for Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description." />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css" />
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/dropdown.css" /> -->

<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-light.css"
          >
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- CONTACT FORM SECTION START -->
    <section class="mb-5">
        <div class="form-area">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row single-form g-0">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                        <div class="left">
                            <h2><span>Contact Us for</span> <br>Business Inquiries</h2>
                            
                            <div class="mt-5 text-white" id="info" >
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-phone fa-2x ms-2"></i>
                    
                            <p class="ms-2"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mt-5 text-white" id="info">
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-envelope fa-2x ms-2"></i>
                                <p class="ms-2"></p>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                        <div class="right">
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-left"></i>
                            <form action="https://formsubmit.co/myemail" method="POST">
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="Name" class="form-label">Full Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Full Name" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="Email" class="form-label">Email Address</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="Message" class="form-label">Message</label>
                                <textarea type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="How can we help you?" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                            
                            <input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="New Contact Form Inquiry!">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

##Test.css

```css
@import "./.fonts.css";

body {
    background: hsl(233, 47%, 96%);
}
.form-area {
    padding-top: 7%;
}
.row.single-form {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 20px -5px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
}
.left {
    background: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
    padding: 200px 98px;
}
.left h2 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 48px;
}
.left h2 span {
    font-weight: 100;
}
.single-form{
    background: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}
.right {
    padding: 70px 100px;
    position: relative;
}
.right i {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 80px;
    left: -27px;
    top: 40%;
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}
.form-control {
    border: 2px solid hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
}
.right button {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: hsl(0, 0%, 15%);
    width: 180px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.right button:hover{
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 15%);
}


/*responsive*/

@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px){
    .right i {
    top: -52px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    left: 50%;
}
}

@media (max-width:767px){
    .left {
  padding: 90px 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
.left h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
}
.right {
  padding: 25px;
}
.right i {
  top: -52px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  left: 46%;
}
    .right button {
    width: 150px;
    padding: 12px 0;
}
    
}

#info {
    display: flex;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
@import "./.fonts.css";

body {
    background: hsl(233, 47%, 96%);
}
.form-area {
    padding-top: 7%;
}
.row.single-form {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 20px -5px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
}
.left {
    background: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
    padding: 200px 98px;
}
.left h2 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 48px;
}
.left h2 span {
    font-weight: 100;
}
.single-form{
    background: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}
.right {
    padding: 70px 100px;
    position: relative;
}
.right i {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 80px;
    left: -27px;
    top: 40%;
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}
.form-control {
    border: 2px solid hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
}
.right button {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: hsl(0, 0%, 15%);
    width: 180px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.right button:hover{
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 15%);
}


/*responsive*/

@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px){
    .right i {
    top: -52px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    left: 50%;
}
}

@media (max-width:767px){
    .left {
  padding: 90px 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
.left h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
}
.right {
  padding: 25px;
}
.right i {
  top: -52px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  left: 46%;
}
    .right button {
    width: 150px;
    padding: 12px 0;
}
    
}

#info {
    display: flex;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Home | </title>

<meta name="description" content="Write an awesome description for your new site here. It will appear in your document head meta (for Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description." />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css" />
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/dropdown.css" /> -->

<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-light.css"
          >
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/contact-form.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- CONTACT FORM SECTION START -->
    <section class="mb-5">
        <div class="form-area">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row single-form g-0">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                        <div class="left">
                            <h2><span>Contact Us for</span> <br>Business Inquiries</h2>
                            
                            <div class="mt-5 text-white" id="info" >
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-phone fa-2x ms-2"></i>
                    
                            <p class="ms-2"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mt-5 text-white" id="info">
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-envelope fa-2x ms-2"></i>
                                <p class="ms-2"></p>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                        <div class="right">
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-left"></i>
                            <form action="https://formsubmit.co/myemail" method="POST">
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="Name" class="form-label">Full Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Full Name" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="Email" class="form-label">Email Address</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="Message" class="form-label">Message</label>
                                <textarea type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="How can we help you?" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                            
                            <input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="New Contact Form Inquiry!">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isn't the name attribute required for the inputs so formsubmit can label the data?